# why keras model.fit using gpu lead to Segmentation fault？

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using tensorflow==2.0.0 and keras==2.3.1 to implement Yolo3 and Yolo4.

Scenario 1: When I using cpu and model.fit() it can work.

Scenario 2: When I using gpu and **eager mode**(tf.GradientTape()), it can work.

Scenario 3: When I using gpu and model.fit(), it always can't work and throw error *Segmentation fault*.However, somtimes it works and print only one message *WARNING:tensorflow:Method (on*.

So I try to shrink batch size.It still have error.I also use **gdb** to locate the error which get:

```
Thread 75 "python" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

[Switching to Thread 0x7ffe45fff700 (LWP 6825)]
0x00007fff833b3a62 in tensorflow::NodeExecStats::Clear() ()
from /home/andy/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so.2
```

or

```
Thread 90 "python" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffe017fa700 (LWP 19479)]
0x00007fff88f757d1 in tensorflow::(anonymous namespace)::MaybeCopyInputToExpectedDevice(tensorflow::EagerOperation*, tensorflow::Device*, int, tensorflow::Device*, tensorflow::RunMetadata*, tensorflow::TensorHandle**) [clone .constprop.461] ()
from /home/andy/anaconda3/envs/tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
```

I am new to **gdb**.I don't know why every time run it get different message.

Comment: SegFaults are normally a signal of internal Tensorflow bugs. You might want to open an issue on github, adding the full traceback of the error (and whatever other information they'll require).

Comment: So you mean I need to report this error to Google?

Comment: To the Tensorflow team, on their GitHub project: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

Comment: All right, thanks~